# Linker error in OpenCV with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to do some image rectification using OpenCV .I got some code from http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.opencv/14644 but the problem is the moment I include CvCalibFilter in my code it starts to give me linker error.More precisely this is what it says :-

> : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall CvCalibFilter::~CvCalibFilter(void)" (??1CvCalibFilter@@UAE@XZ)

I saw some posts of people having the same problem but could not find a solution anywhere.Can someone help?
Thanks!

P.S. I installed OpenCV to work with Visual Studio as mentioned in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio go to...

*Project > 'Your Project Name' Properties... > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input >*

Then go to *Additional Dependencies* and add the appropriate .lib files, these should do the trick: `cv200.lib cxcore200.lib highgui200.lib`

Comment: cvCalibfilter would be in cvaux.lib

Comment: I have cv210.lib cxcore210.lib highgui210.lib instead .Should it be a diff?  @Martin: I have "#include cvaux.h" at beginning of my code

Comment: add `cvaux210.lib` to your linker inputs, in addition to the ones you mentioned in your comment

Answer (score 0):

Is it only CvCalibFilter you have a problem with?

If so, is it in the build of OpenCV you have? Has it been renamed?

Do you have the latest version, did you build it yourself?

Comment: Yes I face the problem when I have cvcalibfilter in my code.I do not copy the entire code from the link I mentioned @top .I move step by step.The moment I include this filter I get stuck.